# Dropdownlist with tableview crash when add to superview

Tags: swift, tableview, dropdown, superview

I would like to call tableview dropdownlist, but it will crash on viewcontroller because of superview!.addSubview(transparentView) clicked on textfield textbegin. How can i use the dropdownlist with tableview in the best way. please help with the dropdownmenu

I would like to call function from viewController

```
 private var dropdownMenu: RegistrationDropdownMenu = RegistrationDropdownMenu(identifier: RegStepTwoIndentifier.regStepTwoTable)
RegistrationDropdownMenu().openDropdownMenu(inputField: inputField)
```

```
class RegistrationDropdownMenu: UITableView {
    private var identifier: String
    private var inputField: InputField?
    private var data: [RegistrationAPIResponse.RegistartionItems] = []
    private var transparentView = UIView()
    private var maxHeight: CGFloat = 300
    public var isDropdownMenuOpened: Bool = false

    init(identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        super.init(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        configDropdownMenu()
    }

    private func configDropdownMenu() {
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.register(RegistrationCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        self.allowsSelection = true
        self.separatorStyle = .none
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.backgroundColor = Styles.dropDownMenuBackgroundColor
        self.layer.borderColor = Styles.borderColor.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = Styles.borderWidth
        self.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension RegistrationDropdownMenu {
    public func openDropdownMenu(inputField: inputField) {
        isDropdownMenuOpened = true
        self.inputField = inputField
        data = RegistrationDataRepository().get(for: .birthdayMonth)
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else { return }
        let frames = inputField.convert(inputField.bounds, to: keyWindow)
        superview!.addSubview(transparentView)
        superview!.addSubview(self)
        self.reloadData()
        self.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
        self.frame = CGRect(
            x: frames.origin.x,
            y: frames.origin.y + frames.height - 1,
            width: frames.width,
            height: maxHeight
        )
    }

    public func closeDropDownMenu() {
        self.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
        isDropdownMenuOpened = false
        self.data = []
        guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else { return }
        let frames = inputField!.convert(inputField!.bounds, to: keyWindow)
        self.transparentView.alpha = 0
        self.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 0)
    }

    @objc private func backgroundBehavior() {
        closeDropDownMenu()
    }
}

extension RegistrationDropdownMenu: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableview: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableview: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row].label
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: Styles.dropdownMenuTextSize, weight: .regular)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = Styles.dropDownMenuTextColor
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableview: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return Styles.dropdownMenuRowSize
    }

    func tableView(_ tableview: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        inputField!.text = data[indexPath.row].label
        closeDropDownMenu()
    }
}

class RegistrationCell: UITableViewCell {}
```

```
[TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has been added to a window. Table view: <Hong_Kong_International_Airport.RegistrationDropdownMenu: 0x7ff007190800; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (20 312; 335 300); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000f971b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001c6e700>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {335, 572}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <Hong_Kong_International_Airport.RegistrationDropdownMenu: 0x7ff007190800; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (20 312; 335 300); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000f971b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001c6e700>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {335, 572}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <Hong_Kong_International_Airport.RegistrationDropdownMenu: 0x7ff007190800>>>
```

Comment: ur passing an empty 
private var identifier: String

this is the reason the app got crashed.

Comment: `superview` is nil because you have not added `RegistrationDropdownMenu` to any view yet and yet you force unwrap with `superview!` which is most likely the cause of your crash

Comment: Thank you guys. but the table not showing up. there are error on superview.